# Don't Have A .minecraft Folder on Windows 10 PC

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I downloaded a map for my Minecraft game (I have Minecraft Windows 10 Edition) but it won't show up in the actual game. I looked up how to download maps onto Minecraft Windows 10 and it said that the .minecraft file would be in %appdata%. I searched that in the file explorer in downloads but it's not there!

Comment: click the windows tab and paste %appdata% there not in downloads

Comment: And then you can navigate to .minecraft and place the world in saves

Comment: Guys he has "Minecraft: Windows 10 Edition". Not the classic minecraft we are used to. I'm sure it's different

Comment: Directories should stay the same though should they not?

Comment: No. It is a windows app so it has a different directory.

Answer (score 3):

Type `run` in your search bar, click it. Then type `%appdata%`. After that navigate into `.minecraft/saves`

Comment: For windows 10 edition: visit this link: http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-pocket-edition/mcwin10-discussion/2599778-how-do-i-install-a-map-for-minecraft-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

So because you are on Minecraft Windows 10 Edition, I doubt the map will work as it is probably for the main release of the game. 
Anyway, if you really want to try or are just curious where the directory is, I found it in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_(long string of letters and numbers)\

The problem is that WindowsApps is not only a hidden folder but was very hard to get into. I ended up transferring ownership of the folder to myself in order to gain access. I tried on another computer and didn't have this problem. If you don't feel comfortable messing with system files, don't bother unless you're feeling brave because, although slightly interesting,
access to the files is kind of useless to you because the map *probably* doesn't work on this version. My guess is it requires the full Minecraft release, available from minecraft.net

So to answer your question: There is no .minecraft folder for Minecraft Windows 10 Edition as it is a different game from the original one. Installing your map is a complicated process and the map is most likely incompatible with your game.

Comment: So then, how can I save or retrieve lost worlds if I have the Windows 10 Minecraft app version?